# Вопрос по crashreporter Fabric

Tags: java, android

Кто использует этот крашрепоретер у себя в проекте?

Подскажите как правильно сделать. Вот [следуя документации](https://www.fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) его установить не сложно.

Но тут вопрос насчет последней строчки которую нужно добавить в свой код

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Я так понимаю это инициализация самого `Fabric`...

1. Так вот вопрос в том, мне нужно добавить эту строку на каждое
   активити, чтоб `Fabric` мог регистрировать ошибки или вполне
   достаточно сделать инициализацию при запуске приложения на первом
   экране?
2. И второе я проверил приложение следуя примеру краштеста и
   действительно в дешборде отображается ошибка при краше приложения,
   но вопрос в том, будет ли отображаться обычная ошибка допустим
   которая была отловлена в `catch` блоке? Или нужно дописывать что то в `cathch` блок?

Просто сейчас не возможности протестировать на устройстве, поэтому решил узнать если кто то использует `Fabric` в своем проекте, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

1. Достаточно сделать инициализацию в наследнике App
2. Если отлавливаешь ошибку при помощи `catch`, то [отправить лог нужно самому](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html)